# LINQ where Clause doubt

Tags: c#, linq, where-clause, clause

I have tried one where clause in Linq to get details about `User`s those who are `Active` and `AllowLogin` is also true.

So how can I compare the table values (both are boolean values) with true or false?

Answer (score 14):

Just use something like:

```
var query = from user in context.Users
            where user.Active && user.AllowLogin
            select user;
```

Alternatively, you can write the same query without a query expression:

```
var query = context.Users.Where(user => user.Active && user.AllowLogin);
```

Comment: If all you want is the details (instead of the whole User), you can do a "select user.Detail"

Comment: Yes - but I assumed that when the OP said "details" he meant "all fields of the table" rather than a specific field called "details".

Comment: I took the freedom to format the question to match Jon's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var qry = (from en in Contaxt.tblStatDefinitions
                   where en.Name == "Sunandan"
                   select en.id).Single();
```